# std::function callback with arguments in observer pattern (placeholder on register subject)

Tags: c++, function, bind, std, observer-pattern

I am working on an input manager class based on the observer pattern using std::function and std::bind.

The input manager class is derived from a class called "Observable" which includes a method called "Register(...)":

```
  std::map<Event, std::vector<std::function<void()>>> m_observers;

  template <class Observer, class... Args>
  void Register(Event&& event, Observer&& observer, Args&&... args)
  {
      m_observers[std::move(event)].push_back(std::bind(std::forward<Observer>(observer), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
  }
```

So you can register subjects to the input manager. The input manager than dispatches the current input (given from the OS) to all its listeners (subjects). For this, the registered callback of the subject will be called. This callback should be of arbitrary signature.

In a subject class I call register on initialization like this:

```
GameApp::InputManager.Register(
    InputType::Keyboard,
    &IntroGameState::OnInput,
    this,
    //sf::Event()
    std::placeholders::_1
  );
```

The following compiler error occurs:

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   12.0\vc\include\functional(900): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::tuple_element<0,_Ftuple>'

If a pass a valid argument to the register method (as args...) such as "sf::Event()" everything's working. But at this moment I only would like to register the subject and tell which callback should be called in case of the input manager have some input for the subject. I want to give an argument FROM the input manager TO the subject. And not vice verca. At registration of the subject to the subject I don't know the arguments. The arguments should be given from the manager to the subject (via the callback). So I thought a placeholder in the register code (on subject's side) would be fine. But this leads to the compiler error as mentioned above.

Any ideas how I can solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to fill a slot of the form

```
std::function<void()>
```

with the result of a call to `std::bind` with `std::placeholders::_1` as one of the arguments. The binder provides an `operator()` that takes one argument, the `std::function` expects to be able to call it with none. That's why this doesn't compile.

If I understand what you're trying correctly, your map should be of type

```
                                            // v---- here ----v
std::map<Event, std::vector<std::function<void(SomeClass const &)>>> m_observers;
```

Where `SomeClass` encapsulates the data you need to pass back to the callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's working now. I changed to m_observers to: std::map<Event, std::vector<std::function<void(const void*)>>> m_observers; and my Callback handler looks like this: void IntroGameState::OnInput(const void* data)
{
  const sf::Event* eventData = static_cast<const sf::Event*>(data);
  // further code
} But I think it's dirty :)

Comment: I thought... Any suggestions for improvement? :) It should be an universal observer. So, I do not like to pin down a fixed type. Maybe a polymorphic approach?